# How can a bitcoin ATM charge less than the average bitcoin transaction fee?

Tags: transaction-fees, bitcoin-atm

As of this writing, the average bitcoin transaction fee is over $30, according to [this chart](https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/bitcoin-transactionfees.html#3m). However, I just bought $20 worth of bitcoin from an ATM, and they charged me a fee of around $2.00.

My understanding of the fee for a transaction is that it is a function of market forces, the number of bytes in the transaction, and the time you are willing to wait for your transaction to be added to the blockchain. Overall however, I had the impression that at a given time these fees are relatively constant per transaction. So I would expect that the owners of the ATM would have to spend something around $30 in fees to give me my $18.00.

I asked a [similar question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/66079/how-can-coinbase-charge-less-than-the-average-transaction-fee/) about coinbase.  In that case the explanation was that coinbase wasn't actually transferring any bitcoin on the blockchain.  However, this ATM printed me a new wallet, which I assume means a new bitcoin address was created and bitcoin was transferred to it on the blockchain.

What don't I understand?

Comment: How long did it take before the transaction was confirmed?

Comment: Maybe they want to gain trustworthiness and provide maximum value to their customers. Also GDAX(they are Coinbase dedicated exchange) doesn't charge network fee at all, I see it as as strategy to create pleased customers. No one really know what they are up to.

Comment: What exchange rate did they give you?  If the Market rate at the time was $15,000 USD : 1BTC, but this ATM charged $16,500 USD : 1BTC, then they charged you a premium in the exchange rate, not the "fees".

Comment: @Monstrum it looks like it took about 3 hours to be included on the block chain.  The fees are indeed more than the bitcoin transacted.

Comment: @abelenky The order of magnitude you have there is about what they charged me in the exchange rate.  However, the fees that the ATM owners paid the miners - when converted to USD using the exchange rate that google reports - were still more than the amount I put into the ATM.